# Realtek r8168 network card problems

Tags: drivers

Installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a HP 510a.  Only getting 100base-T connection out of my 1000base-T network IC chip.  When I updated the driver the connection disappeared completely from Setting/Network screen.  I have installed the latest drivers for the built-in LAN card (Realtek R8168)...

Tried: 8.045.08 & 8.046.00...  Neither script installs successfully....  From a fresh install of Ubuntu workstation I am missing several apps called in the autorun.sh script...

Tried to follow unixblogger notes to the letter... Added the missing apps...

Now I get these errors/warnings:

W: possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/nvidia/gv100/acr/bl.gin for module nouveau (many varieties of this line)

AND:

load module r8168
mod probe: ERROR: could not insert 'r8168': Operation not permitted
Updating initramfs.  Please Wait.

Anybody have a better driver to install and/or better directions???

Comment: Not an expert but I strongly suspect the issue had nothing to do with the driver.